# How to handle error response in Next.js 13 Server Component?

Tags: next.js, error-handling, fetch, token, next.js13

So I'm trying to fetch data that needs token header for authorization in Server Component `page.tsx`. The data itself comes from external backend/API and it can response with different status code. If `Unauthorized` it will response with status `401`, if `Not Found` it will response with status `404`. Here I already provided a handle for each different error status:

```js
const getItems = async (): Promise<IGetItemsResponse> => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}items`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies().get('access_token')?.value}`,
    },
  });

  if (res.status === 404) {
    notFound()
  }
  if (res.status === 401) {
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.cookies.delete('access_token');
    response.cookies.delete('expiry_token');
    return response;
  }
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
  }
  return res.json();
};

export default async function Page() {
  const items = await getItems()
  return <ItemList initialData={items}/>;
}
```

When it response with `404` Next.js succeed showing the nearest `not-found.tsx`. However the problem here is the `401` error, I don't know why Next.js won't delete the cookie as I already handle the `401` error response there. Instead deleting the cookie, Next.js just run the `throw new Error('Something went wrong!');` right away which lead to showing the nearest `error.tsx`. And then in `error.tsx` component, it shows the right error message in development build, but in production build it shows this different error message:
[error message in production build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raHBg.png)

Been searching and debugging for hours, yet still don't know why it won't handle the error.
**Please is there any way to properly handle this different error status in Next.js 13 Server Component?**
I need to at least delete the token cookies if it responses `401`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.js with the new App Router version (13.4 or newer), the [next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#deleting-cookies) recommend the use of the package `next/headers` for the cookie manipulations on server side like below.

Use `NextResponse` statement after the cookie delete.

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

async function yourFn() {
  cookies().delete('cookie-name')
}
```